# Texture not getting displayed on plane

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So I'm trying to write a refraction shader, where there is a glass ball on a plane. My problem is that the texture is that the texture is not getting displayed on the plane.

Plane code:

```
GLfloat plane[4][5] =                           // s, t, x, y, z
{
    0.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f,   0.0f, 100.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,     80.0f,   0.0f, 100.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,     80.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,
};    
void DrawPlane()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);    
    glVertex3fv(plane[0]+2);    
    glVertex3fv(plane[1]+2);    
    glVertex3fv(plane[2]+2);    
    glVertex3fv(plane[3]+2);    
    glEnd();
}
```

And my fragment shader looks like this:

```
varying vec3 varPosition;
varying vec2 varTexCoords;

uniform vec3 sphere_center;
uniform float sphere_radius;
uniform float sphere_refractive_index;

uniform vec3 eyePosition;    

uniform sampler2D texture;

out vec3 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec3 ray_direction = normalize(varPosition - eyePosition);

    float a = dot(ray_direction, ray_direction);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(ray_direction, eyePosition - sphere_center);
    float c = dot(sphere_center, sphere_center) + dot(eyePosition, eyePosition) - 2.0 * dot(sphere_center, eyePosition) - sphere_radius*sphere_radius;

    float test = b*b - 4.0*a*c;

    if (test >= 0.0) {
        //there is an intersection with the sphere
        //here I refract the ray
    } else {
        //no intersection with the sphere 
        //we test for shadow    
        if (test >= 0.0) {
            //the point is in shadow
            vec3 black = vec3(0.0);
            fragColor = mix(texture2D(texture, varTexCoords).rgb,black,shadowIntensity).rgb;
        } else {
            //the point is not in shadow
            fragColor = texture2D(texture, varTexCoords).rgb;
        }           
    }       
}
```

The situation is that the sphere gets painted, but the plane remains grey. The problem is maybe with my texCoords, since if I change the varTexCoords parameter in the texture2D function (to something like position.xz) it paints the plane (incorrectly of course). But it seems to me that I have everything necessary there.

Attribute arrays:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(plane[0]+2));       
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(plane[0]));
```

I bind the attribute locations and I enable the vertex attribute arrays:

```
glBindAttribLocation(program->id(), ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(program->id(), ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS, "texCoords");

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);
```

I have tried *everything*. Maybe the error is something trivial and I can't think straight anymore because I am **this** close to losing my mind.

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: glEnable(TEXTURE_2D); OpenGL is state based.

Comment: I have it in my initGL() function.

Comment: @Krythic: `glEnable(TEXTURE_2D);` is completely irrelevant for the shaders, it only influences fixed-function pipeline.

Comment: @derhass I'll fix your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You are *not* using your texture coordinates. YOu do set up some attribute pointers, but these are never used, because you are using immediate mode `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` to draw the plane, without ever specifying any tex-coords (so the shader will see a constant value for that attribute). The attribute pointers which you did set up will only be used if you actually issue a draw call which is based on vertex arrays, like `glDrawArrays()` or `glDrawElements()`.

Comment: Okay, so if I write `glTexCoord2f(x.0f, y.0f)` before every `glVertex3fv(plane[0]+2)` it should work right (where _x_ and _y_ would be the corresponding one and zero) ? Sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Using `glVertex`, `glColor`, `glTexCoord` etc. will set the deprecated builtin attributes for the fixed function pipeline. You are using shaders with _generic_ attributes, so you must use`glVertexAttrib` with the various attribute indices. OpenGL only makes the guarantee that `glVertex` is equivalent to setting generic attribute 0, so the reason you at least got the correct vertex coords was most likely that `ATTRIB_VERTEX` happens to be `0`. However, you shpuld better drop immediate mode altogether.